# Set TabStops on a ListBox control in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, winapi, listbox, refresh

I first came onto that post [here](http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/system/cb_enumclipboardformats.htm) by Randy Birch about listing clipboard formats. As you can see, he is using Visual Basic 6 and also a .Refresh method on List1 after sending the LB_SETTABSTOPS messages to the WNDPROC handling the window corresponding to his "List1" ListBox

Since the .Refresh method is not available in VBA (and also the .Hwnd, but that is less a problem withing [this post by C. PEARSON](http://www.yqcomputer.com/84_77136_1.htm) and `Private Declare Function GetFocus Lib "user32" () As Long`), I tried to 'mimic' it.

[Apparently](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/subhagpo/2005/02/22/whats-the-difference-between-control-invalidate-control-update-and-control-refresh/), the .Refresh method invalidates the whole client area of the ListBox Window, and then sends a WM_PAINT message to the WNDPROC bypassing any other pending messages in message queue, causing an immediate repaint of the update region, which should be the entire visible "List1" ListBox in this particular case.

My config :

```
Debug.Print Application.Version
Debug.Print Application.VBE.Version
Debug.Print Application.OperatingSystem

#If VBA6 Then
    Debug.Print "VBA6 = True"
#Else
    Debug.Print "VBA6 = False"
#End If

#If VBA7 Then
    Debug.Print "VBA7 = True"
#Else
    Debug.Print "VBA7 = False"
#End If
```

Results in:

```
16.0
7.01
Windows (32-bit) NT 10.00
VBA6 = True
VBA7 = True
```

Now my attempt #1 :

```
Option Explicit

Private Const LB_SETTABSTOPS As Long = &H192
Private Const EM_SETTABSTOPS As Long = &HCB

Private Const RDW_ALLCHILDREN = &H80
Private Const RDW_ERASE = &H4
Private Const RDW_ERASENOW = &H200
Private Const RDW_FRAME = &H400
Private Const RDW_INTERNALPAINT = &H2
Private Const RDW_INVALIDATE = &H1
Private Const RDW_NOCHILDREN = &H40
Private Const RDW_NOERASE = &H20
Private Const RDW_NOFRAME = &H800
Private Const RDW_NOINTERNALPAINT = &H10
Private Const RDW_UPDATENOW = &H100
Private Const RDW_VALIDATE = &H8

Private hWndList1 As Long

Private Type Rect
    Left As Long
    Top As Long
    Right As Long
    Bottom As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
Private Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetFocus Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function UpdateWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Boolean
Private Declare Function VarPtrArray Lib "msvbvm60.dll" Alias "VarPtr" (ByRef lpRect As Rect) As Long
Private Declare Function RedrawWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByRef lprcUpdate As Rect, ByVal hrgnUpdate As Long, Optional ByVal flags As Integer) As Boolean
Private Declare Function InvalidateRect Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByRef lpRect As Rect, ByVal bErase As Boolean) As Long
Private Declare Function GetUpdateRect Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByRef lpRect As Rect, ByVal bErase As Boolean) As Boolean
Private Declare Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByRef lpRect As Rect) As Boolean
Private Declare Function CreateRectRgnIndirect Lib "gdi32" (ByRef lpRect As Rect) As Long
Private Declare Function GetClientRect Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByRef lpRect As Rect) As Long
Private Declare Function GetDesktopWindow Lib "user32" () As Long

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim ListWindowUpdated As Boolean
Dim ListWindowRedrawn As Boolean

ReDim TabStop(0 To 1) As Long

TabStop(0) = 90
TabStop(1) = 130

With List1

    .Clear

    .SetFocus
    hWndList1 = GetFocus

    Call SendMessage(hWndList1, LB_SETTABSTOPS, 0&, ByVal 0&)
    Call SendMessage(hWndList1, LB_SETTABSTOPS, 2, TabStop(0))

    Dim rectList1 As Rect
    Call GetWindowRect(hWndList1, rectList1)
    Dim lprcList1 As Long
    lprcList1 = VarPtrArray(rectList1)

    ListWindowRedrawn = RedrawWindow(hWndList1, rectList1, lprcList1, RDW_INVALIDATE)
    ListWindowRedrawn = RedrawWindow(hWndList1, rectList1, 0, RDW_INVALIDATE)

    MsgBox "ListWindowRedrawn = " & ListWindowRedrawn & " and RDW_INVALIDATE message sent"
    'Call RedrawWindowAny(hWndForm2, vbNull, 1&, RDW_INVALIDATE Or RDW_UPDATENOW Or RDW_ALLCHILDREN)

    ListWindowUpdated = UpdateWindow(hWndList1)
    MsgBox "ListWindowUpdated = " & ListWindowUpdated

End With

End Sub
```

My attempt #2 :

```
    Dim ScreenRect As Rect
    Dim hClientRect As Long
    hClientRect = GetClientRect(hWndList1), ScreenRect)

    Dim udtScrDim As Rect
    Dim lReturn As Long
    Dim hRegion As Long

    udtScrDim.Left = 0
    udtScrDim.Top = 0
    udtScrDim.Right = ScreenRect.Right - ScreenRect.Left
    MsgBox "Screen width = " & ScreenRect.Right - ScreenRect.Left
    udtScrDim.Bottom = ScreenRect.Bottom - ScreenRect.Top
    MsgBox "Screen height = " & ScreenRect.Bottom - ScreenRect.Top
    hRegion = CreateRectRgnIndirect(udtScrDim)

    If hRegion <> 0 Then
       lReturn = RedrawWindow(0, udtScrDim, hRegion, RDW_ERASE Or RDW_FRAME Or RDW_INVALIDATE Or RDW_UPDATENOW Or RDW_INTERNALPAINT Or RDW_ALLCHILDREN)
    End If
```

After many attemps, I still can't get the client area to be updated with the custom tabstop positions. But the attempt #1 above still seems to be the more logical to me. It works fine, no errors, but nothing changes, any item (containing vbTab) in the ListBox won't be affected, even with a later `UserForm1.Repaint`.

Please help :)

Comment: *"Please help"* is not the type of 'question' Stack Overflow encourages users to ask. See [ask] for a good introduction.

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite an answer but more a workaround :

My understanding of the problem (and of Randy Birch) :

The only explaination is that the VBA Listbox control simply can't deal with LB_SETTABSTOPS messages. Indeed I also tried sending the LB_SETTABSTOPS message later, but it's still ignored. Same thing with the invalidate message and WM_PAINT.

That might be why the Office devs implemented the .ColumnWidth property in VBA Excel which can do exactly the same things that what I was trying to do above.